# python,SocketServer : How to use the main thread timeout method in a multi-threaded scenario

Tags: python-2.7, socketserver

my request is close main thread after more than 2 min.i called serve_forever() ，but don't know how to close the main thread.my codes:

```
import SocketServer,socket
import threading,time,re


last_request_time = 0


class ThreadSocketServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn,SocketServer.TCPServer):pass


class RequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

def handle(self):
    global last_request_time
    last_request_time = time.time()
    # print last_request_time
    intact_data = []
    while True:
        data = str(self.request.recv(1024))
        intact_data.append(data)
        # if response[-16:-1].find('clientcomplete'):
        if re.search('clientcomplete', data):
            print 'server recv complete'
            self.request.send('Finished')
            break
    self.request.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

server = ThreadSocketServer(('192.168.3.33',12345),RequestHandler)
# server.handle_request()
server.serve_forever()
```

i tried server.handle_request(),but it can't seem to support multi threading.